# Why does JS don't round values less than 1?

Tags: javascript, rounding

We are facing some rounding issues in my team, and when testing some behavior we saw this in Chrome's console:

```
15*0.023
0.345
15*1.023
15.344999999999999
```

I'm not able to understand what is going on. Any help?

Comment: Would you mind adding your code?, please

Comment: @Neobugu um.... do you not see it?

Comment: Thank you @epascarello for the duplicates, but they don't explain why one result is rounded but not the other.

Comment: The floating point math operation has issues with some values. The links discuss the issue of the binary vs base 10 conversion. A lot of time it is better to do the decimal math like `15*1023/1000`